# Visual Studio Code - Target of URI doesn't exist 'package:flutter/material.dart'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-packages

I've just set up my Macbook for flutter development,

So I downloaded flutter SDK, and placed it in my **Documents**. After, I set up my path variable to work with **flutter** in my command line.

I execute the command `flutter create todolist` so I achieve a blank project.

I also set up my visual studio code with **Dart-Code** so I have the proper syntax highlight, IntelliSense, etc.

So when I open visual studio code, it highlights the `import` method, like the following image:

[image: first line of the code]

This means that it also highlights the classes that are correct, making it completely hard to understand if it's a real error or not.

I have executed both `pub get` and `flutter packages get` and got everything correctly.
I have my path variables all correctly.

Why is it highlighting it cannot find that 'import' package?

Comment: What does the status bar say about the Dart version? See also https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/318. See also https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/198#issuecomment-310620677

Comment: It's correct, it says "Dart - 1.24.0-dev.6.7" @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: But if I go to my flutter project and execute ***flutter run*** it installs properly on my device

Comment: Do you have a non-Flutter Dart SDK installed?

Comment: I have flutter sdk in my ***documents*** folder, and have dart installed with homebrew

Comment: Does `flutter analyze` show any issues? If it doesn't, then this sounds like a VSCode specific issue.

Comment: Is this problem still occurring? If so, does the bottom right version indicator show something like `1.25.0-dev.7.0 (Flutter)`?

Comment: I just stumbled across this and I know it's been a while, but did you manage to resolve this? Can you reproduce it? I'd love to take a look (I'm the author of Code's Dart/Flutter plugin). My guess is that Dart Code has not realised your project is a Flutter project (which I think @TehSkull was suggesting), which might be because the flutter project is in a sub-folder?

Comment: restarting android studio did not work for me.  `flutter pub get` worked

Answer (score 551):

The issue is due to the missing packages which are being used in the project.
Therefore, in order to install the same, navigate to the folder where the project is present -> cmd -> execute the following commands:

- `flutter packages get`
- `flutter packages upgrade`
- restart VScode/Android studio

source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: If you're able to reproduce this; I'd love to take a look. You shouldn't need to manually restart VS Code to fix issues like this (if you do, I'd like to fix). You can raise issues at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/new thanks!

Comment: Notice that it's now `flutter packages get `

Comment: I just closed the folder in the VSCode and opened again. this resolved:)

Comment: (this worked for me) but its very odd that, we still need to do a editor restart just to connect to existing files.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu (`flutter packages get` and then restarted VSCode). Thanks!

Comment: Notice that it's now ```flutter pub get``` https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: This worked for me without any sort of restart or reload of VS Code

Comment: I closed Android Studio project then reopened. The error was solved.

Comment: Wow! restart VSCode is a required step. I spent so much time experimenting with `flutter pub` commands, but still got the same error. Even after being 100% sure that package exists in system cache.

Answer (score 76):

Run these commands: -

```
flutter clean

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade //( Optional - use if you want to upgrade packages )
```

Then restart Android Studio or Visual Studio.

Comment: $ flutter clean

$ flutter packages get

$ flutter packages upgrade

_If you are running on vscode do it in the debug mode._

Answer (score 40):

Author of the Dart Code plugin here! From the screenshot, I would say this is because your flutter project is in a sub-folder of the folder open in Code. We only scan the opened-folder to check whether it's a Flutter project - which then changes the SDK we launch and also enables the Flutter functionality (like the daemon and debugger).

You should re-open the "todo" folder directly.

If you want to have multiple projects open together, use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces), since Dart Code is multi-root-aware and will check each of the folders in the workspace when deciding if it needs to enable Flutter functionality.

### Update

This case should be better supported in the Dart plugin now, so opening the immediate parent folder of a Flutter project should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Flutter 1.0, when using VS Code and following the Flutter.io Get Started tutorial, this lack of package detection is rearing is ugly head again. The plugin properly runs "flutter packages get", but VS Code doesn't see the package and does all of the code underlining as if it were an error across the relevant classes. Restarting VS Code make the error lines go away once I loaded the project folder again. Maybe it's a regression error?

Comment: @CokoBWare Do you mean when using the `Flutter: New Project` command? I just tested it here and once the package update had finished, all red squiggles disappeared.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny was fixed for Flutter Projects but not for Dart Projects.  Either way for now I just right click on pubspec.yaml and run Get Packages

Comment: @user603749 there's no reason this shouldn't work for Dart too. Please open an issue on GitHub with details of what you see so I can investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

If you have used the `flutter packages get` command and the error still persists, you can simply reload VS code the `Developer: Reload Window` command. Simply type that in after pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` (`Cmd+Shift+P` for Mac users). It will clear the error. It's like refreshing VS Code.

Answer (score 18):

Restart the VS Code you will see magic!
If that's not work then check the indent of your dependencies in the pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in Android Studio as well as VS Code. I only had to run these lines in my terminal/command prompt and problem was solved. There was no need to restart any of the IDEs again

- **flutter packages get**

Optionally you also run.

- **flutter upgrade**

Answer (score 10):

Open the project after **deleting .idea folder** and **.dart_tool**

Answer (score 9):

Now this happens most of the time to me, whenever I open some old project(flutter project), it is basically because of not downloading or not having the packages to refer, for the VS Code, In simple just blindly do a  `PUB GET` or just hit `CTRL/CMD + s` in pubspec.yaml file, and you are good to go (sometimes it might take some time to get everything set (depends on your system specs)).

---

old answer starts here:

Simple thing I did after Someone said here to restart the VS Code and I did that, and now everything works fine.

For me it was because just when I was creating project I got an notification for updating my dart(or related) extension and for that I did it and boom as my project started, it just gave me around 30 errors which do scared but the simple fix was to restart the editor.

Answer (score 6):

Open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p), type flutter: get packages (should autocomplete); after it resolves open the command palette again and type reload window and execute the command. This should resolve the issue as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Close the VS Code and Run it again

Answer (score 6):

Restart your IDE, and run these commands:

- flutter clean.
- flutter pub get.
- flutter upgrade.

if they didn't work, then check your dart SDK path.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way to get Dart-Code to reliably find your Flutter install and use it is to create a new `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable and set it to your Flutter path.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check for correct indentation of your package in dependencies
2. if your editor supports, it automatically runs -> **flutter pub get**
3. Either way -> open terminal-> **flutter pub get** or **flutter packages get**
4. check **.packages** file, see if your package is present else reinstall package
5. ***Most important*** : Restart your IDE (Visual studio or Android Studio)

Start debugging your project

Most probably, your errors will be fixed by then

Comment: Most important needs to be at top of the list ;) Thx.

Answer (score 4):

try to run `flutter clean`

then restart VS Code. This did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. I had both `VS code` and `Android studio` installed in my system.

The error was in `VS code`.

When i opened the same project on `Android studio`, the dependency was not actually added to `pubsec.yaml`. I added it there and ran `pub.get`.

When I returned to `VS Code` and everything was working fine.

So, Try opening it in other editor if you have, or through `NotePad`.

Edit:

Opening `widget_test.dart` and running it should also solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also happened to me while trying to run the project inside of another directory.

Worked by using the root directory of the main project

Answer (score 1):

Just add 
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
in pubspec.yaml file
[please check http documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http#-installing-tab-)

Answer (score 1):

If you execute From the terminal: "Run flutter packages get" and the error continues, check is all packages directories are listed at '.packages' file. - Sometime you have the packages, but it is not configured at this file.

Answer (score 1):

Execute one of the following:

- `flutter upgrade`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter packages get`

Answer (score 1):

> Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the
>   .packages file that is no longer available. The repository from which
>   the 'flutter' tool is currently executing will be used instead.
>   running Flutter tool: /opt/flutter   previous reference  :
>   /Users/Shared/Library/flutter This can happen if you deleted or moved
>   your copy of the Flutter repository, or if it was on a volume that is
>   no longer mounted or has been mounted at a different location. Please
>   check your system path to verify that you are running the expected
>   version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your
>   path).

Checking the output of the `flutter packages get` reveals that the reason in my case was due to moving the flutter sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/[xxxxx]/flutter/bin
```

For me, it works:

```
flutter upgrade

flutter packages get
```

You can check with

```
flutter doctor

flutter --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to *pubsec.yaml* file and add this directly after *cupertino_icons*:

```
webview_flutter:
```

Then press **Packages get** on the top right corner and it will work fine with you.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependencies.
for example:- `import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';`
in the above package if we only use this package then it shows error 
but if we add dependencies in pubspec.yaml 
such as

```
dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    audioplayers: ^0.14.1
```

[image]

then click on packages get.

as you see this, I can also insert dependencies so if you insert dependencies along with your package then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying use the audio players flutter package. Once I added it to pubspec.yaml and tried to import it to main.dart, I got the same error.

I tried to restart my IDE but that didn't help so i tried running
`flutter packages pub cache repair` and it worked.

Comment: Please add more context to your answer to say how it's different from other answers here and make it more useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the property `name` in `pubspect.yaml` all your package in lib folder turn to red with the error Target of URI doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

I was using (goggle location picker (with much more customisation in functions and UI) ) so I copy this package(complete) and using in my app in one folder but since dart code analyser analyses one flutter project so I found that those which are referencing from inside of this package is not working then I copy only lib folder(of google location picker) in my original project folder and voila this worked for me.
This solution took me a time of 3 days.
I know this is not the question but it might help someone to save 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Android Studio with the rflutter_alert package. After inserting the dependencies, I imported the package in my project with ctrl+space key and I have added import 'package:rflutter_alert/'; the problem is that this was not correct. The correct form was package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart
[right vs wrong comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHccY.png)

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue with the bloc package, after i restarted visual studio i installed the package again using `flutter pub add bloc` and it installed properly this time. Note that i tried installing it several times, this time it was a charm

Answer (score 1):

My case was different, I pretty much tried everything suggested but with no luck :( .

In my case it didn't find several packages, for some reason it could find the folder of the packages, but not the main file of it, after not finding answer online for this, i started to look into these packages and check their dependencies and saw that I was missing one, still not sure why it found the folder but not the content of it because of a dependency, anyhow, the dependency in my case was meta, which is for annotations, many packages uses it, after adding it to all relevant module in our project, pub get... and walla no errors, phew this one was very annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to save pubspec.yaml before running "flutter pub get". Restarting Visual Studio Code is not enough. That was my solution. Sometimes when you work with intellij you forget that ...

Answer (score 0):

When you usually get this error message:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:foo'. Try creating the file
>   referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

Example:

> Target of URI doesn't exist:
>   'package:random_string/random_string.dart'. Try creating the file
>   referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

```
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';
```

It is because a dependency is missing.

So all you have to do is find out what packages are needed by googling your package name.

[image]

Install the dependency:

```
$ flutter pub get
```

and add the dependency in the pubspec.yaml file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was following the Flutter get started tutorial and VSCode could not find the package for `english_words`, despite it showing in `pubspeck.lock` and `.packages`. Hot reload didn't work.

To make it work, I stopped the instance and re-run it - so I didn't have to restart VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with the same issue on Android studio and tried everything restarting, packages get, repair everything, But none of these solution worked. The only thing which worked was to set the encoding of the packages file giving error to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think this was possible: I had to delete flutter folder and reinstall it from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just restarting vsCode you can just hit ⌘+r or CTRL+R in Windows, this will reload your VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:provider/provider.dart'.

I had this show up when trying to import - import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

I was using Android Studio

I closed Android studio and restarted it and everything was fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after that I ran the following code:

- flutter pub add firebase_auth
- flutter pub add firebase_core

Answer (score 0):

- run `flutter pub add firebase_core`

**Most Important** - Goto your flutter installation directory and check if Flutter_core is there, if it's not there, run `flutter pub add firebase_core`

If it's not fixed still try these as mentioned everywhere

- flutter pub get
- Restart Visual Studio Code or Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

[image]

go to `settings` / `language & framework` / `dart`   and enable project 'YOUR_PROJECT' then support it

Answer (score 0):

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade

restart VScode/Android studio

If you used the flutter package get command and the error still persists, you can reload the VS code with the Developer: Reload Window command. Just type this after pressing Ctrl+Shift+P (Cmd+Shift+P for Mac users). It will clear the error. It's like refreshing VS Code. this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have screwed my IDE totally.

Solution for me was to run two commands:

```
flutter downgrade
```

and then

```
flutter upgrade
```