# Target of URI doesn't exist 'package:flutter/material.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

My Flutter IDE (Android Studio) doesn't recognize `material.dart` anymore! It happened suddenly, I was working normally then my PC turned off because of CPU 100% consumption and when I restarted I found this problem.

Comment: Restarting the IDE usually fixes it. You can also try deleting `~/.dartServer/.analysis-driver`

Comment: I restarted my IDE several times but no clue :( ! and when trying to upgrade flutter or flutter packages it shows an exception  "Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly."

Comment: Sounds like a harddisk problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the mentioned directory? Perhaps the disk is too small?

Comment: harddisk is 1 To not small at all ! my pc is ASUS i7 7th generation also so hard issu i think ! I didn't understand why should i delete the folder you mentioned?

Comment: It's a cache for the dartAnalyzer with a ton of files wich might be corrupted. Deleting causes it to be recreated (I didn't have a need to do that since months, but worth a try I think).

Comment: `flutter packages get` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Flutter Issue Fix: 18-April-2020**

It happened due to :

1. You have created a project and then you try to push the code to Git ( and keeping your vscode open)
2. Your package needs to update using command flutter packages get ( simply from vscode menu choose terminal and then run this command )
3. If you still it didn't fix your issue, simply go to File Menu, choose Close Folder, it fixes your issue.
4. Last option restart VSCode.

Answer (score 34):

1. ctrl -> Shift -> A (Find Action)
2. Search for "Dart Analysis"
3. Click the icon that says "Restart the Dart Analysis server"
4. The red underline disappears from the package import and everything works.

Comment: finally, I am able to run my 1st project, thx @MohamedMesalm +1

Comment: Didn't fix it, but `flutter packages get` fixed it

Answer (score 17):

I tried this solution and it worked just perfect:

open terminal from the project directory
and run

```
flutter packages get
```

Comment: In my case, I had to run "flutter packages upgrade" then. Hope It helps someone :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution that worked for me: inside your pubspec.yaml file, make sure that the name field (it's the first line of your pubspec.yaml file) has the correct name of the project. If it doesn't, change it and run pub get.

Answer (score 2):

Check bupspec.yaml file. Something may be removed from there. I had the same issue and found out this problem and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look into Flutters Github Issues there can be many causes.

1. Your git causes this error ([issue 19384](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19384))

Just delete every entry in your projects .gitignore on your maschine.

2. There are some missing flutter packages ([issue 17016](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17016))

Even when you've just installed flutter yet it can occur that some packages are going to be missed.
Going to the root of your Flutter project via command prompt and typing the command `flutter packages get` will fix this.

Comment: This one, combined with the proposed VSCode restart from here, worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909653/visual-studio-code-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packageflutter-material-dart

Answer (score 1):

I only re-save my old file. Then restart VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete flutter folder and reinstall it from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to remove `:` colons from the app description in the pubspec.yaml file, and run

```
flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
```

and then run
`flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you delete manually delete flutter package from `Dart packages`. The solution in this case is to reinstall flutter SDK by erasing current `User/flutter` folder and downloading a new one. Then run `flutter packages get` and you should see all dependencies in place.