# Flutter | Dart : Target of URI does not exist

Tags: flutter, http, dart, package, dependencies

I am making my first Application to build an Android App with Flutter.
I am using Android Studio as IDE.
The problem is when I import the http package:

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

I get an error :

> error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:http/http.dart'.
>   (uri_does_not_exist at [flutter_crypto] lib\home_page.dart:3)

That's my code :

```
  Future<List> getCurrencies() async{
    String cryptoUrl = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=50";
    http.Response response = await http.get(cryptoUrl);
    return JSON.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/44909653/10409567

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add the HTTP dependency to pubspec.yaml as per below.

```
 dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      http: ^0.12.0
```

With the dependency added you then need to run the following command to update/install required packages:

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

Hope this helps

Comment: with vs code you may need to restart the ide as well at the end

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have added the dependency to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
```

You will also need to:

`flutter packages get`

Answer (score 3):

For any upcoming problem with importing packages from dart please go to official Dart website packages and search for needed package and you will find solution up there.

---

for your issue go to:

1. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http
2. Installing tap https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http#-installing-tab-
3. follow guide steps:

   In pubspec.yaml file:@ dependencies

   ```
    dependencies:
        http: ^0.12.0
        flutter:
   ```

(NB: please make sure that http & flutter or any other attribute inside dependencies are aligned as above and they are at same line)

---

```
In terminal run below command:
```

> $flutter packages get

Answer (score 0):

run: dart pub --trace get --no-precompile in android srudio Terminal