# Flutter imports randomly stop working, for no apparent reason

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

As the project we're working on gets bigger and bigger, a colleague started to face a lot of problems involving `pubspec.yaml`. He used to get rid of them by manually deleting Dart's cached dependencies, but this time he's having an issue that looks unsolvable.

When importing libraries within our own package’s `lib` directory, `import 'package:...'` doesn't work, only relative paths. For instance, consider the following structure:

```
my_package
└─ lib
  ├─ utils.dart
  └─ api.dart
```

If he tries to import `utils.dart` inside `api.dart`, he's restricted to using relative paths:

```
import 'utils.dart'; // Works!
import 'package:my_package/utils.dart'; // Error: Target of URI doesn't exist: package:my_package/utils.dart.
```

Such behavior is not consistent, since the project has many other modules in identical contexts that are not required to use relative path to import. Furthermore, no one else in the team was having this problem, but suddenly another on the team started experiencing the same. It's spreading! We tried reinstalling Dart, Flutter, IntelliJ, but the error persists.

The issue disappears if we delete the project and clones it again from git. However, amazingly, the error returns as soon as we restart and invalidate IntelliJ's cache.

Oddly enough, these errors don't interfere with the project's execution, it is still able to run. But since the import is broken the IDE can't link to the file and won't do its regular syntax analysis.

**Any ideas on solving this problem, or even how to start looking for solutions?**

Comment: i had the same issue using vs code and i came across an answer that     is because your flutter project is in a sub-folder of the folder open in Code not sure if it applies ti intelliJ      https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831134/10409567

Comment: @Ggriffo I checked your link, but that's not our case, unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug I've been encountering recently on vscode too. Usually reloading the IDE is enough. Likely a bug

Comment: use flutter build clean
then restart the ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in Flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio , just use invalidate cache + restart option
https://prnt.sc/1q2h8j7 (check screenshot)

Comment: The OP clearly stated that invalidating cache and restart is triggering the problem. Furthermore there's an already accepted answer