# "Target of URI doesn't exist:

Tags: flutter

Everytime I install a new package, I get this error "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:"

I tried everyting flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade, flutter clean, restart Android Studio, nothing works... Only restarting Windows makes it work.

Even If I can see the package in dependencies it's not working.

Any idea why ?

Comment: have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909653/visual-studio-code-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-packageflutter-material-dart

Comment: Yes, already did everything on it

Answer (score 0):

you should try to restart the Dart analysis Server.

Dart Analysis tab > the red button

Have a nice day

[image]